# HAProxy authentication from Scrapy

Tags: authentication, proxy, scrapy, authorization, haproxy

I'm configuring a haproxy server to use for my Scrapy scraper. The scraper will not always use the proxy so a custom middleware would not be a pleasant solution. I have configured basic auth in the proxy as such:

```
userlist basic-auth-list
        group is-admin
        user *username* password *passwd* groups is-admin

backend backend_name
   acl devops-auth http_auth_group(basic-auth-list) is-admin
   http-request auth realm devops unless devops-auth
```

and am able to send a curl through it by using: **curl -x proxy_ip:port -u username:pass url**. 
In my scraper I have tried:

> headers={'Proxy-Authorization': "user:pass encoded with base64"} and
>
> headers={"Authentication":"user:pass encoded with base64 --- *base64 bc the docs on this header say it should be base64 or a variation of it*"}
>
> headers={"Authorization":"user:pass encoded with sha-256 and des"}
>
> headers={"Authorization":"Basic user:pass encoded with base64/sha-256/des --- *doing this bc proxy can have the pass encrypted in only sha-256 sha-512 md5 and des and i have user pass in sha-256 and des*"}
>
> headers={"Authorization": basic_auth_header(user,pass)}
>
> meta={'proxy':'http://username:pass@ip:port'}

and all of them return a **401 Authorization required**. I have also noticed that when trying to curl with my haproxy as such:
curl -x proxy_ip:port --proxy-user username:pass url or
curl -x 'http://username:pass@proxy_ip:port' url
I also get a 401. The only way it works is by using the -u curl option which is a server authentication. Does anybody know how I can configure haproxy to be accessible through --proxy-user as well?

Answer (score 0):

To use --proxy-user, see option:

`http-use-proxy-header option`

Add this option in the frontend and enable basic authentication:

`http request authentication unless {http_auth (admin)}`